# multiply every number in an array and writing to new array

Tags: solidity

how to do that?
i've been trying something like this

```
    uint[] public numbers = [1, 2, 3];
    uint[] public numbers2;

    function multiplyArray(uint a) public {
        uint b = numbers.length;
        uint counter = 0;
        for (uint i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        {
        numbers2[i] = numbers[i] * a;
        counter++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `numbers2[i] = numbers[i] * a;` with `numbers2.push(numbers[i] * a)`